# Joomla 3 Changing admin page path

Tags: joomla3.0

Is this possible to change path to admin page in Joomla 3? 
The standard is `domain.xxx/administrator` but I would like to have something like `domain.xxx/backoffice`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but it is not recommended.
You will have many problems to make updates, etc.

For security propuse, I use the plugin [Admin Exile](http://www.richeyweb.com/development/joomla-plugins/71-adminexile-for-joomla-16), which requires adding a value after the url and if not present, jump directly to the homepage of the site.

[Admin Exile](http://www.richeyweb.com/development/joomla-plugins/71-adminexile-for-joomla-16)

Answer (score 0):

As the other guy told, it can be done but it's not recommended cause of updates.

Another security method which doesn't need any plugin is protecting by .htaccess 
( https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/ )